# Layered Elements Linq

Tags: xml, linq

Trying to parse out this xml file to get a list of Elements but I'm having difficulties in doing so.

Here's my Xml file:

```
<STORES>
  <Stores1>
   <TEST>
    <ClientID>200</ClientID>
    <FormTypeID>101</FormTypeID>
   </TEST>
   <PROD>
    <ClientID>200</ClientID>
    <FormTypeID>102</FormTypeID>
   </PROD>
  </Stores1>
  <Stores2>
   <TEST>
    <ClientID>201</ClientID>
    <FormTypeID>717</FormTypeID>
   </TEST>
   <PROD>
    <ClientID>201</ClientID>
    <FormTypeID>719</FormTypeID>
   </PROD>
  </Stores2>
</STORES>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is pull back all of  child elements depending on what I feed the querys XNames parameter for the Elements method call. Like so

```
  var elements = (from x in xDoc.Elements("Stores1")
                      where x.Name.LocalName == "TEST"
                      select x).ToList();
```

So the list would contain all of TEST Elements for Stores1 like this:

```
<ClientID>200</ClientID>
<FormTypeID>101</FormTypeID>
```

I get nothing returned at the moment. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xDoc.Elements("Stores1")` returns all of the direct child elements of the document named `Stores1`.

You want `xDoc.Element("STORES").Element("Stores1").Elements("TEST").Elements()`; you don't need any LINQ